# Tensorflow flow_from_dataframe put all the pixel to white

Tags: tensorflow, keras

He,
I am using flow_from_dataframe to manage image but at the end of the computation i get all the wrong pixel of the image, below i show all my code, can someone help me

```
batch_size = 12 
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale = 1. / 255,\
zoom_range=0.1,\
rotation_range=10,\
width_shift_range=0.1,\
height_shift_range=0.1,\
horizontal_flip=True,\
vertical_flip=False,)


train_generator_left_cc = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
target_size=(256,256),
x_col="left_cc",
y_col=["lb","lm","rb","rm","left_cc"],
color_mode="rgb",
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode="multi_output",
shuffle=False,
interpolation="bilinear"

)

train_generator_right_cc = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
target_size=(256,256),
x_col="right_cc",
y_col=["lb","lm","rb","rm", "right_cc"],
color_mode="rgb",
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode="multi_output",
shuffle=False,
)

x1,y1=train_generator_left_cc.next()
x2,y2=train_generator_right_cc.next()

i=11
image = x1[i]
label = (y1[0][i],y1[1][i],y1[2][i],y1[3][i],y1[4][i])  # categorical from one-hot-encoding
print("Image shape: ", image.shape)

print(label)
pyplot.imshow(image.squeeze())
pyplot.show()
image = x2[i]
label = (y2[0][i],y2[1][i],y2[2][i],y2[3][i]) # categorical from one-hot-encoding
print(label)
pyplot.imshow(image)
pyplot.show()

#i put the directory of the image in the label of the dataset to make test
image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file(y2[4][i]), channels=3)


arr_ = np.squeeze(image_decoded) 
pyplot.imshow(arr_)
pyplot.show()
```

and here there is the result image:
[result of the flow_from_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Za3.png)

[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuCjF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tensor flow library there is a bug to process the resize function so I build a custom generator for the image